# Backbone still leaking memory after several attempts at cleaning

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am having issues at solving backbone memory leaks, so far I attempted to clean the views using jquery CleanData when the views are removing from the DOM.

Each time a view is removed (even via jQuery .html()) it hit the dispose() method that should theoretically kill all references that stop the view from being collected. Unfortunately the app just build up memory

code below,

```
Backbone.View.prototype.dispose = function(){
    // unbind all events, so we don't have references to child views
    this.unbind();
    this.off();
    // if we have a collection - unbind all events bound to this context
    this.collection && this.collection.off(null, null, this);
    // do the same with a model
    this.model      && this.model.off(null, null, this);
    delete this;
};
```

clean data :

```
$.cleanData = function( elems ) {
    $.each( elems, function( i, elem ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            $(elem).trigger("dispose");
        }
    });
    oldClean(elems);
};
```

The code work, dispose is hit (I added the event in the view) but it's never collected anyway when I change page.

(About the dispose event..)
I do not explicitly call remove on all views. the app container is emptied, jQuery does cleanData. I added an event dispose & I trigger that func in cleandata

Comment: I am confused at the way you seem to remove the bindings.. `$(elem).trigger("dispose");` is a jQuery selector and you are supposed to clean up the Backbone view. So why not just call `this.dispose()` when inside the view

Comment: because I do not explicitly call remove on all views. the container is emptied, jQuery does cleanData and I added an event dispose that call this function

Comment: Have you looked at Marionette which extends the capabilities of Backbone.js.  Marionette seems to do a very good job of keeping Backbone clean and free of memory leaks.

Comment: You *have* to explicitly call `dispose` on all views. Triggering `dispose` on the DOM will *not* call the method in the view. If you don't want to do this, look into using an extension like Marionette that will automagically close and cleanup all child views for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is `delete this` doesn't do what you thought it would. It depends on how you initiate your view. Do you assign your view to any variable or initiate it in a scope that live beyond the point where you change your page?

Also, there is a function [remove()](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1032-L1036) on Backbone View

More on JavaScript `delete` http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete